# Is there any requirement of using Phone gap (cordova) with appgyver (supersonic or Steroidsjs)?

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, steroids

I want to know Is there any requirement of using phonegap(cordova) with appgyver(supersonic or Steroidsjs). Can I use hardware API that are provided by Phone gap in appgyver(supersonic and Steroidsjs). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is no as such requirement for using cordova with Supersonic. Supersonic is full-fledged framework in itself and has every set of tool from development to production and deployment. 
However you can use Steroids debugging tool with your cordova project to take advantage of livereload.
See docs here -
http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/cli/usage-with-cordova/
And yes you can use some basic hardware API with Supersonic. See here - 
http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/api-reference/stable/supersonic/device/